# GridView - Restore scroll position

Tags: android, gridview

I have problem with restore GridView position using approach like below. Using `gv.setSelection(index);` works ok, but need position GridView more precisely. When i use `gv.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);` scroll is restored good, but only when `index` is `0`. With ListView the same approach work ok. OS: Android 5.0.2.

save:

```
index = gv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View v = gv.getChildAt(0);
top = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - gv.getPaddingTop());
```

restore:

```
gv.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
```

layout:

```
<GridView
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1px"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="140dp"/>
```